# Sql server use pivot function to restruct data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table of data in SQL Server 2012, shown below. What I would like to do is query the data but restructure the layout. There is one column called 'factor' that contain 7-8 different labels which have a corresponding value (value column). What I would like is to have the factors as columns going across - please see the desired output section to see what I mean. What is the best way to write a query to view my data as such?

***Desired Output***

```
pdate     abc     def   ghi
1-1-13    1       3     2
2-1-13    1       3     2
```

**Table example**

```
factor     pdate     value
abc        1-1-13    1
def        1-1-13    3
ghi        1-1-13    2
abc        2-1-13    1
def        2-1-13    3
ghi        2-1-13    2
abc        3-1-13    1
def        3-1-13    3
ghi        3-1-13    2
abc        4-1-13    1
def        4-1-13    3
ghi        4-1-13    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as outisnihil mentioned a better approach would be to use `PIVOT`

Using `PiVOT`

```
  SELECT pdate
        , [abc]
        , [def]
        , [ghi]
    FROM YOUR_table
    PIVOT(SUM([value]) FOR factor IN (
                [abc]
                , [def]
                , [ghi]
                )) AS val
```

---

Using `CASE`...
You can use a case for every factor value to generate a new column in your output.

```
SELECT pdate
, CASE 
WHEN factor = 'abc' SUM(value) END abc
, CASE 
WHEN factor = 'def' SUM(value) END def
, CASE 
WHEN factor = 'ghi' SUM(value) END ghi 
FROM YOUR_table GROUP BY pdate
```

Comment: Don't you think a PIVOT would make more sense here?

Comment: @outisnihil: Added a version using PIVOT

Comment: +1: For correct answer, dynamic version is supplemental

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic version if you don't want to hard-code the [factor] values...

```
If      Object_ID('tempdb..#factorDateValues') Is Not Null Drop Table #factorDateValues
Create  Table #factorDateValues (factor Varchar(50), pdate Date, value Int)

Insert  #factorDateValues (factor, pdate, value)
Values  ('abc','2013-01-01', 1),
        ('def','2013-01-01', 3),
        ('ghi','2013-01-01', 2),
        ('abc','2013-02-01', 1),
        ('def','2013-02-01', 3),
        ('ghi','2013-02-01', 2),
        ('abc','2013-03-01', 1),
        ('def','2013-03-01', 3),
        ('ghi','2013-03-01', 2),
        ('abc','2013-04-01', 1),
        ('def','2013-04-01', 3),
        ('ghi','2013-04-01', 2)

Declare @sql Nvarchar(Max)

Select  @sql = Coalesce(@sql + ',','') + '[' + factor + ']'
From    #factorDateValues
Group   By factor
Order   By factor

Set     @sql = 'Select  pDate,' + @sql +
               'From    #factorDateValues
                Pivot  (Max([value]) For factor In (' + @sql + ')) As val'

Exec    sp_executeSQL @sql
```