# Simulate PIVOT table in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2000

I know that SQL Server 2000 doesn't support `PIVOT` table.

Let me tell you all about my issue and maybe you can help me with a solution.

I have a table with clients and projects.

```
client    project 
------    --------
A         1111
A         1112
B         2222
B         2223
C         1234
D         1235
```

I would like to swap rows with columns. So the output table will be:

```
A      B       C       D
---------------------------
1111   2222    1234    1235
1112   2223    NULL    NULL
```

It's possible in SQL Server 2008 simply using `PIVOT` table, but the server we need to use is 2000.

The clients and projects are dynamic of course.

**Is there anything to get this result?**

**UPDATE:**

I know that there are many questions in here about pivot in SQL Server. I read almost everything. 
One solution is to do many case statements, but this doesn't return  what I need.

**It will return:**

```
A       B       C       D
----------------------------
1111    NULL    NULL    NULL 
1112    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    2222    NULL    NULL
NULL    2223    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    1234    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    1235
```

Which is not what I want since I will be exporting it to EXCEL with drop-down lists and it will create a lot of empty strings in the lists.

Comment: Had answered a similar question here [LINK to POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562167/sql-server-use-pivot-function-to-restruct-data/22562265#22562265)

Comment: @Yuck, this will not work since it will create huge table where each row has only one project for one client. I'm trying to have one row with multiple project.

Comment: @SoulTrain, please see my additional comments

Comment: You are not asking for a pivot; you are asking for four independent lists in the four columns.  This is a pain in SQL Server 2000.  It is time to update.  There are three major releases since then and the software is no longer supported (http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2011/03/09/important-support-changes-for-sql-server-2000-and-sql-server-2005.aspx).

Comment: Aside from the other recommendations / comments, in order to even simulate a pivot for what you want, you would need to have a sequence number per letter to compare first vs second, then it COULD be done easier.

Comment: Fetch the data for one drop-down at a time, i.e. 4 queries like `SELECT Project FROM table WHERE Client = 'A'`